Is repeatedly murdering your companion pawn the intended Dragons Dogma 2 experience?
Being intrigued by the pawn customization system, I was recently researching for info about Dragons Dogma 2 to see if it could be worth buying.
While looking for info about the game, I stumbled upon a new feature that most players seemed to hate: Dragon Plague.
Basically, pawns can be infected by an illness that isn't normally displayed in the character status screen, unlike every other affliction (apparently it can be detected from some signs like idle animations, glowing eyes, and so on — until they bug out or you simply hire another player pawn that is already about to explode). If the character is not "cured" for a while, then they will go crazy the first time the player sleeps at an inn, killing every NPC — including Quest ones — in said city. At that point, the game "mocks" the player for having ignored something that was purposely hidden from the game UI interface and handwaved as a plot element.

As the game is still pretty new and bug-rigged, it is still quite unclear what the outcome of this event is: some players defend the game and swear that every NPC respawns (with no lore explanation) in about a week while others claim quest npc stay dead, potentially rendering entire quest chains unplayable (unless you use wakestones to resurrect them — a rare resource in the game that lucky enough can also be bought as paid DLC...). Some even claim that the entire main story arc can be rendered unplayable and the game has a "fail safe" mode that triggers a new quest for "go and kill the final boss" if the main quest is broken beyond fixing.
Leaving the Plague effects aside, no cure seems to exist for it. The only way to remove the plague for a pawn is either dismiss them (not possible for your own pawn) or... having them die and then summon them again from the Rift.
For this reason the common consent among player is that every time you want to sleep at an inn you should:

dismiss every optional pawn you have
kill your own pawn "just to be sure" (some claim that due to a bug the visual clues for the plague sometime do not trigger). When your main pawn dies their affection decreases (apparently this vale influences the ending) and they often get permanent scars on their body.

The game marketing loves to empathize the pawn mechanic as a way to give the player the experience to play with companions, and having liked the Arfasys system in SAO:Fatal Bullet that was something that got me interested in looking into it. Yet, the actual gameplay implementation seems to enforce the use of pawns as disposable tools instead, punishing players that dislike the idea of repeatedly killing their own companion they designed as a regular part of the game experience.
I am therefore asking: Do the game really want you to use your own pawn as a disposable tool that should be tossed in the Brine every time you get back to the city in order to avoid your (only) save slot to be ruined? Can you play the game while still avoiding having to "euthanize" your companions to be safe?

My experience... I've never had this notorious dragon plague during my first entire playthrough (about 60 hours), and 2nd playthrough (about 30 hours right now).
I might be just lucky, or just I wasn't aware of that (but I never saw dead civilians in any city nor the popup). Maybe because I wasn't actively fighting against dragons (they are the source of plague). Maybe because I'm not using inn that much (camping is much better; they won't require money, but does almost same effect as using inn. Only downside is that sometimes you get raided by monsters).
So my answer is -
No, the devs do not want you to use your (and others) pawn as a disposable tool.
Though, you'd still want to change hired pawns in some occasion, because hired pawns can't level up. If you accidentally picked plagued one... just change them to new one. I myself frequently changed pawns due to that system, so in that sense yes, they are disposable tools.

Do you remember ever getting the "tutorial prompt" about the plague? Did your own pawn die to other causes (could they have been cured by a death you didn't willing cause)? The fact you rarely sleep in the city could be a big part of this too.

@Ꮢedacted Yes, I've seen that tutorial prompt during first playthrough. My pawn did not "completely" died (they can go down before they die), though only one time my own pawn tried to swim in the river for some reason, and died. But, I think that's irrelevant, since that death happened in first 3 hours of the playthrough. After that, I decided to stop visiting near the river or sea or even lakes, because I don't want my pawn(s) to die. Soloing in this game is seriously hard.

And I do sleep in city or town (to get my pawn quest to be renewed). At least once in a 3 to 4 city or town visit. Otherwise I just go camping.
